# Auto generate UML (use class + data dictionary) designs In Visual Studio 2013 based off project?

Tags: uml, project, visual-studio-2013

So I was wondering if it's possible to add any sort of designs from my project and most importantly the UML Class and Data Dictionary.

Comment: Did you try anything? Eg. search MSDN for UML?

Comment: Yeah, couldn't find anything regarding the data dictionary but the class diagram can be displayed, but only the classes and not actually any of the links.

Answer (score 0):

It does *[something](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx)*. For C# only.

For to get an acceptable diagram, you have to edit it by hand in every tool. 
But other tools (VP, EA), support refreshing the ready diagram according to changes in code.

With VS, even with Visio, you have to do it by hand again and again...